# create gcs storage in node

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions')
   const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  let gcs = new Storage ();
  const os = require('os');
  const path = require('path');
exports.onFileChange = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(event => {
      console.log(event);
     const bucket = event.bucket;
     contentType = event.contentType;
     const filePath = event.name;
    console.log('file detected')

  if(path.basename(filePath).startsWith('renamed-')){
      console.log('already renamed this file')
    return;
  }

 const destBucket = gcs.bucket(bucket);
const tmpFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), path.basename(filePath));
 const metadata = { contentType : contentType }
  return destBucket.file(filePath).download({
destination : tmpFilePath
 }).then(() => {
          return destBucket.upload(tmpFilePath, {
          destination:'renamed-'+ path.basename(filePath),
          metadata: metadata
           }) 


           })

              });
```

the error is:-
`Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: /srv/node_modules/p-limit/index.js:30
} catch {}
^

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
     at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
     at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
     at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/bucke here t.js:25:16)


   `
```

Comment: If you clean up the formatting of this code, it might be easier to tell exactly where the syntax error is.

Comment: This seems like a problem with `p-limit` library that `@google-cloud/storage` and `firebase-admin` rely on... To be precise an **empty "catch" statement** is being considered as a `SyntaxError`, which to be honest should not be a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

The error message implies you have a syntax error in your function.

Change the line `contentType = event.contentType;` to   `const contentType = event.contentType;` and your syntax er